# I can't get the data in appends with json in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I have two models in laravel project Item and ItemImgs

Item.php

```
class Item extends Model
{
    protected $appends = [

        'photo',

    ];

    public function imgs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ItemImage::class);
    }


    public function getPhotoAttribute()
    {
        $img = $this->imgs->first();
        return $img.src;
    }

}
```

it's worked in views

```
dd(Item::all()); //worked
{{ $cane->photo}}; //worked
```

but when I try to get json

```
    return response()->json([
        'items' => Item::with('imgs')->get(),
    ]);
```

// not worked. Got timeout 500

Comment: I suppose there is a problem with the relation. I guess `dd(Item::with('imgs')->get()` doesn't work neither ? be sure of your relation, can't help more here without all elements

Comment: Which kind of error are you getting? Can you please provide me output of `dd(Item::with('imgs')->get())`?

Comment: dd worke, but response not worked 

    return response()->json([
            'canes' => Cane::has('imgs')->get(),
        ]);

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use dot notation in PHP.

```
public function getPhotoAttribute()
{
    $img = $this->imgs->first();
    return $img.src; // Dot notation is not allowed
}
```

but you've to use:

```
public function getPhotoAttribute()
{
    $img = $this->imgs->first();
    return $img->src;
}
```

Comment: it's errata in my question (( 
i use "->" still not worked

Comment: Ok probably because you're trying to reach a related model inside an attribute declaration. Try to insert `getPhotoAttribute` inside ItemImage model.

Comment: Yes. I want get data from relation model inside in attribute. is it impossible? i got "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes" in tinker and 504 error in browser.  Only in json, in laravel views it worked!

Comment: i need Item attribute 'photo' (first or main photo of Item).  Itemimage model don't need this attribute unfortunately.

Comment: To be clear. You should get a list of items with its first pics. You do not need the content of *ItemImage* model except for fist "src". Is it correct?

Comment: That's about right. I need to get a link to the main photo of the item. 
The public function getPhotoAttribute()
    {
        $img = $this->imgs->where('main', 1)->first();
        return $img->src;
    }

Comment: Why using `Img::with('imgs')`. The *with()* statement inside a *get()* operation can be extremely slow. You can get what you need simply with `Img::get()->toArray()` or `Img::get()->toJson()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196475/discussion-between-ilya-vo-and-roberto-ferro).

Comment: public function getPhotoAttribute(){
  $img =  ItemImage::where('item', $this->id)->first();}

It works that way, but it's not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

if what you're trying to do is to get the items that have imgs() then what you should do is query by relationship existence, as mentioned in the docs

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

```
'items' => Item::has('imgs')->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to refer to the linked model tables in attributes. It works in views but gives out a memory error when outputting an array through json.

```
public function getPhotoAttribute(){ 
   $img = ItemImage::where('item', $this->id)- 
   >first();
}
```

It works that way, but it's not elegant.